# How to sort a multidimension array using Excel

Tags: excel

I have an array of dates and corresponding values that I would like to put into date order. The data is stored in cells A1 to B100 with Col A being random dates and Col being its associated data as seen on the attachment. The sorted array will go into E1:F100.

I have been looking at INDEX and SMALL functions but I am not making progress. I can use SMALL to sort the date column on its own but I cannot get the 2nd column to index at the same time

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I do not have O365 so the dynamic array function dont work. Many thanks for your help.

***Typical data:***
[image]

Comment: You've left out some things: 1) Why isn't a copy, paste and sort appropriate? 2) What have to tried so far? and 3) Why isn't that doing what you want?

Comment: Why not just select cell, ctrl+t to convert to table, and sort on date column?

Comment: This is part of a bigger spreadsheet / data base so I cant just do a sort. I have been looking at INDEX and SMALL functions but I am not making progress. I can use SMALL to sort the date column on its own but I cannot get the 2nd column to index at the same time.

Comment: Edit your question and add what you've already tried, i.e. your INDEX/SMALL formula.

Answer (score 0):

For older version of excel you can use this array formula. Remember for large dataset formula will work slow.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$100,MATCH(LARGE($A$1:$A$7+ROW($A$1:$A$7)/1000000,ROW(1:1)),$A$1:$A$7+ROW($A$1:$A$7)/1000000,0),COLUMN(A$1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

If you need faster approach then you have to use a helper column.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome. Much appreciated. Just trying to understand how it works, could you explain the reason for the /1000000?

Comment: `ROW($A$1:$A$7)/1000000` this will make every value of date unique, so that we can retrieve each large value to sort data.